# How/where to report missing packages

Tags: software-center, ffmpeg

I have tried to install the `motion` app, and got a bunch of deps missing at the server, see below. Where and how should I reported?

Distro: Ubuntu-mate 15.04

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil-ffmpeg54_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample-ffmpeg1_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavformat-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavresample-ffmpeg2_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libpostproc-ffmpeg53_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswscale-ffmpeg3_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter-ffmpeg5_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/qt-faststart_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil-ffmpeg54_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample-ffmpeg1_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavformat-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavresample-ffmpeg2_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libpostproc-ffmpeg53_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswscale-ffmpeg3_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter-ffmpeg5_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice-ffmpeg56_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/qt-faststart_2.5.6-0ubuntu0.15.04.1_amd64.deb
  404  Not Found
```